# Java multiple inheritance using two interface having same method but different return type

Tags: java

If i have two interfaces having method named m() one's return type is void and others is int and i want to implement both of these two method  in one class how should it be possible

Comment: Those methods aren't compatible; you can't implement both.

Comment: you'll need to (at least) change the signature of the method.

Answer (score 3):

This will not be possible for the same reason as the following class will not compile.

You can't have two methods with the same name and the same parameters list.

```
public class Clazz {
    public void m() {}
    public int  m() {}
}
```

---

A solution would be to have methods that return an instance of each interface using anonymous classes.

```
public interface One {
    void m();
}

public interface Two{
    int m();
}

public class Clazz {
    One getOne(){
        return new One(){
            @Override
            public void m() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };
    }

    Two getTwo(){
        return new Two(){
            @Override
            public int m() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot not do this.

In Java the return type of methods does not allow to make those methods different

Answer (score 1):

> how should it be possible

it is not possible, because return type is not a part of method signature in Java and compiler will produce error.

You should use different method names like `mVoid()` and `mInt()` (or add method parameters to make signatures differ from each other)

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, if you have two interfaces like this

```
interface A {

    void m();
}

interface B {

    int m();
}
```

it is not possible for a class to implement both. Java 8's new functional interfaces give the methods names like `getAsDouble` (rather than just `get`) to avoid such problems.

If you are using Java 8, and your interfaces have only one method, you don't need to write `implements` at all. Instead you can do this

```
class MyClass {

    public void voidMethod() {}

    public int intMethod() { return 42; }
}
```

Then, an instance `myClass` of `MyClass` is not an `A` or a `B` but you can treat it as either by using method references.

```
A a = myClass::voidMethod;
B b = myClass::intMethod;
```

I don't know whether this solves your particular problem as you haven't given many details, but it's a useful thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

It is **possible**. *If* the methods take different arguments, then it is possible to implement them both.

eg:

```
interface A{
    void m();
}


interface B{
    int m(int a);
}

class C implements A,B{
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot not do this.

In java the return type of a method doesn't allow to make those method diferrents
if you want to do this make sure pass dummy argument in second interface w

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ParentA {
void play();
}
interface ParentB {
    int play();
}

class Child implements ParentA, ParentB {


public void play() {
    System.err.println("Child ParentA");
}
//ERROR : return type is incompatible with ParentB.play()

//So added method with int return type too

public int play() {
    System.err.println("Child ParentB");
}
}
```